finding similarity of keywords between many product reviews to detect duplicates
I have a series of product reviews from multiple websites and am trying to identify reviews that are potentially duplicates (ie very similar in the words used). I know there's a lot of room for potential ambiguity here but hopoing there's a reasonable solution. I'm not interested in sentiment analysis, per se, like how many of these reviews are positive.
I've found some dupes by just SQL querying where they are identical but not ideal. Is there a simple way to use a library like Spacy (have used in past a little bit) or tiktoken to tokenize them and do a similarity score?

There are multiple approach to solve this problem.
1. Using hugging face sentence similarity model
pip install -U sentence-transformers

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
sentences = ["I'm happy", "I'm full of happiness"]

model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

#Compute embedding for both lists
embedding_1= model.encode(sentences[0], convert_to_tensor=True)
embedding_2 = model.encode(sentences[1], convert_to_tensor=True)

util.pytorch_cos_sim(embedding_1, embedding_2)
## tensor([[0.6003]])

2. You can use n gram match.
first do Pre-processing such as removal of stop words, lowercase, lametization. Then check for n gram match and choose a threshold.
3. you can also try cosine similarity match
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

# Example: Replace this with your dataset
reviews = [
    "The product is great! I loved it.",
    "I loved the product. It's great!",
    "This is the worst thing I've ever purchased.",
    "Amazing product, will buy again!",
    "Worst thing ever! Do not recommend.",
]

# 1. Convert text to numerical vectors using TF-IDF
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')  # Remove stop words for cleaner vectors
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(reviews)    # Create the TF-IDF matrix

# 2. Compute cosine similarity for all pairs
cosine_sim_matrix = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

# 3. Flatten the matrix and create a DataFrame of similarity scores
pairs = []
for i in range(len(reviews)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(reviews)):  # Compare only unique pairs
        pairs.append((i, j, cosine_sim_matrix[i, j]))

similarity_df = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=["Review1", "Review2", "Cosine Similarity"])
print(similarity_df)

# 4. Filter pairs with high cosine similarity (e.g., > 0.85)
threshold = 0.85
potential_duplicates = similarity_df[similarity_df["Cosine Similarity"] > threshold]
print("\nPotential Duplicates:")
print(potential_duplicates)

